# Restrict access on webpage using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, apache2.4, restrict

Hey I am currently running into the problem, that I want to **restrict access on some websites** in my html root folder, so I can access them only from my local Network.

The Problem is, that neither the site.conf file works nor the .htaccess file in the root folder of the specific website.

My **000-default.conf** looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/username/htmlfolder
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /home/username/htmlfolder
        ServerName myurl.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /linktomy.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /linktomy.key
</VirtualHost>
```

and my **.htaccess** file looks like this:

```
Require ip 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
ErrorDocument 403 "Access Restricted!"
```

The Problem is, that a syntax error in the .htaccess file is making no error when restarting the apache2 server using `sudo service apache2 restart` and I can still access those websites from a different IP. Using the 2 parameters from the .htaccess file in the 000-default.conf file instead of `Require all granted` is also not doing anything.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Found the solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796680/ubuntu-16-04-cant-enable-htaccess?rq=1) by @chandan-goopta